Question about proving Karp Reduction Transitive
In the answer of here

I'm confused why |f(x)| is polynomial in |x|,
it seemed like a leap.
We know x can polynomial reduce
to f(x), but why the size of problem |f(x)| is polynomial in |x|,
say x is n, and f(x) is 2^n-1,
say x=5, and I paste five 1s as 11111
to enlarge the problem size, can't the problem size outgrow
quickly than the time required to compute the conversion?

The output size of a polynomial time function can’t scale worse than polynomial… the time needed just to write the output down already scales linearly with the size of the output.

@spaceisdarkgreen, Can I encourage you to write that as an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted and the question can be treated as answered?  No need to write any more than that.  The platform works best when you write answers to the question in the 'Your Answer' field, not as a comment.  Thanks!

I don't understand what you're saying in the last paragraph, so let me just explain the solution in more detail.
What they're saying is that the output size $|f(x)|$ of a poly-time function $f$ scales polynomially with the input size $|x|$. This implies the result as follows: The time it takes to compute $g\circ f(x)$ is the time it takes to compute $f$ on input $x$ (which is polynomial in $|x|$ since $f$ is poly-time) plus the time it takes to compute $g$ on input $f(x)$ (which is polynomial in $|f(x)|$ since $g$ is poly-time). Then since $|f(x)|$ is polynomial in $|x|$ and the composition of two polynomials is polynomial, the time for this second computation is polynomial in $|x|$ as well, so the time it takes to compute $g\circ f(x)$ is polynomial in $|x|$ and the result follows.
The reason that the output size |f(x)| has to scale polynomially in the input size $|x|$ I gave in the comments: if it scaled faster than that, then, since computing $f$, amongst other things, needs to write the answer $f(x)$ down, which takes at least $|f(x)|$ steps, the run-time needs to scale at least like $|f(x)|$... so if that's worse than polynomial, $f$ can't be poly-time.
